# rolling function in python ignoring nans

Tags: python, pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_quantile.html

I cant not see how to best ignore NaNs in the rolling percentile function. Would anyone know?

```
seriestest = pd.Series([1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 10])
```

and insert nans

```
seriestest2 = pd.Series([1, 5, np.NaN, 2, 4, np.nan, 9, 3, 8, 10])
```

Now, on the first series, I get expected output, using:

```
seriestest.rolling(window = 3).quantile(.5)
```

But, I wish to do the same and ignore NaNs on the test2 series.

```
seriestest2.rolling(window = 3).quantile(.5)
```

Gives:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    8.0
9    8.0
dtype: float64
```

But I think it gives something like this if we can parse a `skipna=True`, which doesn't work for me:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    5.0
3    2.0
4    4.0
5    4.0
6    4.0
7    3.0
8    8.0
9    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What functionality do you expect when there's a `NaN` in the window?

Comment: I don't think your quantile calculation is right

Comment: @Prune I wish to ignore the NaN and pretend it isn't there, i.e. work off all the integers in that window period

Comment: "Pretend it isn't there" comes in various forms.  For instance, when you get to the first full window `(1, 5, NaN)`, do you want the visible two values only, or do you want to infill with the next available value of 2?

Comment: Ah, Im sorry I wanted it to be the visible 2 values only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that having `nan` values will give you less than the required number of elements (3) in your rolling window. You can define the minimum number of valid observations with `rolling` to be less by setting the `min_periods` parameter.

```
seriestest2.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).quantile(.5)
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to replace `nan` values, with say `0`, you can use `fillna`:

```
seriestest2.fillna(value=0).rolling(window=3).quantile(.5)
```

Comment: This doesn't match the values the OP expects, though, so the OP may have something else in mind.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unclear on how those numbers were obtained. This seems to fit the description of what was expected however.

Comment: Thanks @busybear. Ill give it a go.. I think you have solved what I was aiming to describe

Comment: Also filling with 0 (or any other constant value) may modify the result in the general case (as opposed to ignoring nan values in the window when calculating the statistic)