# How to calculate a rolling function of only defined values in pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've found [How to ignore NaN when applying rolling with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269582/how-to-ignore-nan-when-applying-rolling-with-pandas)

But it didn't help.

- I have arrays where each line item is a specific value for a specific time index for a specific column.
- There may be more than one non-NaN entry per row, but certainly not many.
- I want to calculate a function that calculates the gradient according to the defined values, relative to the index.

Can't work out how to do it with either numpy or pandas.

Advice helpful. pandas.drop_na, skip_na didn't help.

Template for output

```
fa = np.random.randn(10,4)
mask = np.zeros(40, dtype=bool)
mask[:15] = True
np.random.shuffle(mask)
mask = mask.reshape(10,4)
fa[mask] = np.nan
fa
Out[40]:
array([[        nan, -0.57681061,         nan,  0.23047461],
       [ 0.26260072, -0.62024175,  0.35678478,         nan],
       [-0.5781359 , -0.17364336,         nan,         nan],
       [-0.58982883,         nan,  0.07114217,  1.03781762],
       [-0.03906354, -0.49546887,         nan,         nan],
       [-0.3988263 ,  0.21794358,         nan, -0.04167338],
       [ 0.35731643, -0.80956629, -0.29624602,  2.59351753],
       [-0.02804324,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,  0.75344618, -0.52145898,         nan],
       [-0.45565981,  0.26946552,         nan,  1.64095417]])
dx = pd.date_range("2023-01-01", periods=10, freq="S")
df = pd.DataFrame(fa, index=idx)
## Apply function 
df.rolling(3).apply(lambda s: s.sum())
Out[52]:
                            0         1   2   3
2018-01-01 00:00:00       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:01       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:02       NaN -1.370696 NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:03 -0.905364       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:04 -1.207028       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:05 -1.027719       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:06 -0.080573 -1.087092 NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:07 -0.069553       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:08 -0.126387       NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:09 -0.126387       NaN NaN NaN

## What would be good is to have the output array being based only on the defined values
## as if the NaN's weren't there. So, for example in the below array which is made
## from taking the columns and applying dropna to them before running the 
## rolling aggregate function.
2018-01-01 00:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:02       NaN -1.370696       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:03 -0.589829 -1.289354       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:04 -0.039064 -0.451169       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:05 -0.398826 -1.087092       NaN2 1.226619
2018-01-01 00:00:06  0.357316       NaN  0.131681  3.589662
2018-01-01 00:00:07 -0.028043       NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:08       NaN  0.161823 -0.746563       NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:09 -0.455660 0.2133456       NaN  4.192798
```

The last line has been formed by doing

```
df[n].dropna().rolling(3).apply(lambda s: s.sum())
```

on each column, and then filled in by hand.

Now the actual function I want to run uses the time index as an input as well, so it's a bit more complicated than this (otherwise it would easy -- just swap out all the `nan`'s with `0`'s and we're done).

Comment: Why couldn't you set up an input and an expected output _at the very least_ for people to work with?

Comment: @David Boshton the bottom dataframe is the expected result, if so, then on what basis are the values arranged in the rows (I wonder why the values end up in a certain index)?

Comment: Good question @inquirer -- sorry it's not clear. I've built the aggregation with `drop_na` and then backfilled to get the result by hand, inserting `NaN`'s as required where the values don't exist.

Comment: @David Boshton  I understand the install of values in the rows of columns 2, 3. As far as I understand, the values are set to indexes on the third available value. I don’t understand how to set the install values in column 1. In the row with index 2 the value is: -1.370696, and in index 3 (-1.289354) although there are 2 values available at this index? That is, based on the logic in columns 2, 3, the values -1.289354 and -0.451169 should be at indexes 4, 5. In column 0, the values were not calculated, that is, they were simply copied, why?